# Discrete Math, necessary versus sufficient condition question.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I was given this question, and I'm a little confused. A little bit of help would be great.

> Find a condition on $m$ that is sufficient but not necessary for $\frac{m}{2} \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I get that if a condition $x$ is sufficient for $y$, the presence of $x$ guarantees the presence of $y$. Applying that to this question, am I looking for something like a condition $x$ that guarantees the validity of $\frac{m}{2} \in \mathbb{Z}$, but $\frac{m}{2} \in \mathbb{Z}$ is possible without the presence of $x$?

Comment: A pedantically-correct answer to your question would be "yes" :P if you want more than that, maybe ask for more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right. You are seeking a condition, given which the statement holds, but without which the statement could still hold. In a sense, you have to find a condition that asks too much.

That said, $\dfrac m2\in\mathbb{Z}$ means exactly that $m$ is an even number, i.e. a multiple of 2: $m$ being an even number is a necessary **and** sufficient condition (it's the $\Leftrightarrow$ symbol, each thing implies the other).
You need something that is not necessary, so this can't be the answer yet. Since it is something sufficient, though, you are on the right track: now try asking more!

Comment: 1/4m? I get that, thanks so much. But I'm trying to think of one that is now necessary but not sufficient. I'm totally unable to grasp this one.

Comment: Well, in this case you have to ask too little w.r.t. the necessary and sufficient condition. For example, you could ask $m\in\mathbb{Z}$, or $m\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Dear Doug, if you are satisfied with this answer, please accept it. That way, your question won't be seen as unanswered anymore (see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask)). Obviously, if you still have any doubts, feel free to ask!

Answer (score 0):

$m/4\in                                     \mathbb Z$

Comment: I don't want an answer, I want an explanation. >_<

Comment: @DougSmith While your question does ask for "a little bit of help", it would be best to specify explicitly in your question that you don't want a full answer.